# Marvel-like Image Flipping Technique

Tags: software

What software can I use to create the "Marvel" movie like flipping effect that accompanies pretty much every Marvel movie? I am looking to create a home movie on my PC that flips through a bunch of pictures really fast as to show time flying by, so to speak. I do not own Adobe After Effects. Looking for cheap or open source.

Comment: Idk if I would consider it a actually flipping motion, more like rapidly overlaying images on top of each other with a slight motion blur to the right possibly. A lot of movie software can do this

Comment: Or, print the images out, flip them Marvel style and record that with a camera. Make sure there's enough light.

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum: Which software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly to clarify is it this kind of effect your want to create?

I know you dont have after effects and your looking for something free, however you can get a free trial if you dont want to use the software for long.

You can download this at:
www.adobe.com/go/tryaftereffects/

Here is this video tutorial on how to replicate something similar to the marvel style.

Hope this Helps!